# How does Ionic Framework content directive works?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

The documentation is quite empty for the moment. I have this little piece of code in my first tab-dash created by the defautl project :

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="padding">
      <div class="bar bar-header  bar-positive">
          <h1 class="title">Dashboard </h1>
      </div>
      <div>
          <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}}</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This show all my users, except the two firts which are stuck somewhere behind the headbar.
[image: Nicolas and Leonard missing]

How can I get them back down the header, as block divs should ? Why does Ionic acting this way ?

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like the header is using a flex display which messes  my div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use an [`ionHeaderBar`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionHeaderBar/) before your `ionContent` to display your header bar.

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Dashboard</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
     ...
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Because it's a TabView, I had to put

 `<ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">...</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
</ion-nav-bar>`